# icheck checkboxes not working with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, icheck

The main problem I face, is that when I click any label, it checks all the checkboxes not it's related input.

check it on plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZorJLzwVjk1akLknaPu?p=preview)

Note: Click the button first.
I had posted a similar question before but there was a problem with plunker, check this updated one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have rewritten the icheck directive you were using to correctly interact with the model. Here is a working plunk that I hope you can use: http://plnkr.co/edit/toxxrRTfmltyamtI7ZG6?p=preview